# Google Play - Test transactions are being tracked

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

[image: Test Transactions summary under Financial Data]

I am using an email address to test my subscription flow. I am purchasing the product and cancelling it after some time so that I can reuse same email address to test. It logs Active subscription and cancelled subscriptions with real data and messes up the data. Is there a way not to populate this data under Financial reports?

Comment: There are various methods of doing testing with registered test accounts [in the help page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing). Have you tried these? They include: - [test with static responses](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#billing-testing-static) - [test using a registered tester account](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-purchases)

Comment: Yeah I get this part, my question is how to stop the transactions being tracked in Google Play for these test accounts.